# How to prevent default on touch with hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-events, hammer.js

I would like to prevent an anchor from clicking through if it is tapped with a touch device, but to act normally if clicked on with a mouse.

The reason being, on desktop you hover over the anchor to see more information, then click to view the product.

On a mobile, I want the first tap to show info, second to view product.

I've tried no end of variations of the following:

```
$('article.product aside a.link').hammer().on('tap', function(ev) {

    if (ev.gesture.pointerType == 'touch') {
        ev.gesture.srcEvent.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }

});
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Could you make a small jsfiddle?

Comment: Is the `pointerType` recognized correctly when you're on a smartphone?

Comment: I don't think this approach will work, i can't get it working either. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/FUZwZ/2/ If i click it in Chrome on PC it gives me two prompts, one for click and then one for tap. If i tap the same link on my Galaxy Nexus (with Chrome) it just registers the click. I bet it varies between browsers, so i don't think this till work.

Comment: @Bigood yes the pointer type is detected correctly

Comment: @qwerty I've put together a quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qJEne/1/

Comment: @qwerty it's such a pain. Someone must have this type of implementation somewhere. I'm not amazing at javascript so it sort of baffles me!

Comment: Actually, for your use case there's no need to detect the touch. Just make it so that if you click OR hover the `item` you show the `aside`. You're not actually going to be able to click it on PC, because the hover will be triggered, which in turn shows the `aside` on top of it. And on mobile, when you click it, the `aside` will display. See how i mean?

Comment: in your anchor code (e.g. <a href="mylink.html" class="link">click here</a>), change the href="mylink.html", to href="#". This should prevent a tap/link through and trap the tap/link in your javascript giving you full control.

Comment: What about binding two different events for `release` and `mouseup`?

Comment: You cannot reliably determine a user agent by a click event since many mobile devices emulate a click event.  Better to test if a device is mobile by the navigator object and have different function calls based on whether a device is mobile/desktop.  This will allow you the greatest flexibility and most simplicity.  i.e.  It leaves mobile devices to throw tap/touch/vclick/click/etc. or whatever they desire.  Also many mobile devices have a small delay from the time a click occurs and the actual event is thrown, just another consideration...

Comment: Could you add a special class to anchors on mobile, then treat anchors with that class differently?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery mouseover` works on mobile devices (at least, in iOS). I created a fiddle that uses `mouseover`, along with telling the link not to fire without a `opacity` of 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/FyF3b/5/

I tested this in chrome and on an iPhone 4S, and it seems to do what you requested. Let me know if it works on your nexus.

The JS:

```
$('aside').on('mouseover mouseout', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('on'); 
});
$('aside a').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(this).parent().css('opacity') < 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```